# Stateful widget in Scaffold's body

Tags: android, dart, flutter, statefulwidget

I don't understand why in flutter is not possible to have a structure like this:

```
//...
Scaffold(
  //...
  body: myPage(dataList[index])
)
//...
```

Where myPage is a class that extends statefulWidget and returns a ListView. It requires a data parameter that is stored in an array. I want to change the body of my scaffold when I change the index for example with a navigation drawer.

I noticed that:

- if myPage extends statelessWidget all works fine,
- if I have different pages classes that extends statefulWidget all works fine,
- but if I have myPage that requires a data to change the content nothing happend, it doesn't change, it stays on the first page

And Yes, I used the setState method to refresh the layout whenever I change the index.

Is this a bug or I missed something? If it is not a bug, what could I do as workaround? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

I post the code of another page that is simpler with nothing strange where there is anyway this problem (I know in this page I could use a statelessWidget but it should work anyway):

```
class FirstFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  String data;
  FirstFragment(this.data);

  @override
  _FirstFragment createState() => new _FirstFragment(data);

}

class _FirstFragment extends State<FirstFragment>{
  String data;
  _FirstFragment(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Center(
      child: new Text(data),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `myPage`?

Comment: There's either something wrong with `myPage` or its parent. You either forgot a setstate, a didUpdateWidget or failed at using immutability

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post, tell me what do you think

Comment: You are changing `index` varaiable which is in a class which contains Scaffold (which should be Stateful). And the `myPage` is not refreshed.. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I solved with @Amarok answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass parameters from parent widget class to its state - you can access them thru "widget" directive. Also, listen to Lint - all instances should be final in the main class.

```
class FirstFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  FirstFragment(this.data);

  @override
  _FirstFragment createState() => new _FirstFragment();

}

class _FirstFragment extends State<FirstFragment>{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Center(
      child: new Text(widget.data),
    );
  }
}
```